# Insert variable value or default value if empty in a string

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to insert the value of an environment variable in a string or a default value if the corresponding variable is not initialized.

Example:

```
if [ -z $MY_VAR ];
then
    MY_VAR="default"
fi

echo "my variable contains $MY_VAR"
```

I'm however using a lot of variables in my strings and the tests are cluttering my script.

Is there a way to make a ternary expression in my string?

Example of what I want to achieve (it doesn't work):

```
echo "my variable contains ${-z $MY_VAR ? $MY_VAR : 'default'}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I did search "inserting bash conditions in bash strings"...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See [Bash Default Values](https://web.archive.org/web/20140329010157/https://docs.codehaus.org/display/ninja/Bash+Default+Values)

```
→ echo "my variable contains ${MY_VAR:-default}"
my variable contains default
```

Comment: One sentence is not elaborate.Just anything to say what it does or a link.

Answer (score 29):

To actually *set* the value of the variable, rather than just expanding to a default if it has no value, you can use this idiom:

```
: ${MY_VAR:=default}
```

which is equivalent to your original `if` statement. The expansion has the side effect of actually changing the value of `MY_VAR` if it is unset or empty. The `:` is just the do-nothing command which provides a context where we can use the parameter expansion, which is treated as an argument that `:` ignores.